# How to update already existed data with same email ids in insertMany in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, mongodb, bulkinsert

Let say, I have some documents like -

```
[
     {
        fname: "FirstName1",
        lname: "LastName1",
        email: "a@gmail.com"
     },
     {
        fname: "FirstName2",
        lname: "LastName2",
        email: "b@gmail.com"
     },
     ...
]
```

, are already existed in the database. Now I am going to insert multiple documents with insertMany, to that database, where some of the objects contains same email ids, like -

```
[
     {
        fname: "FirstName3",
        lname: "LastName3",
        email: "c@gmail.com"
     },
     {
        fname: "FirstName4",
        lname: "LastName4",
        email: "a@gmail.com"
     },
     {
        fname: "FirstName5",
        lname: "LastName5",
        email: "b@gmail.com"
     },
     ...
]
```

So I need to replace the previous docouments with the other fields which contains same email ids with the inserted one. So I want the databse look like this.

```
[
     {
        fname: "FirstName4",
        lname: "LastName4",
        email: "a@gmail.com"
     },
     {
        fname: "FirstName5",
        lname: "LastName5",
        email: "b@gmail.com"
     },
     {
        fname: "FirstName3",
        lname: "LastName3",
        email: "c@gmail.com"
     },
     ...
]
```

Is there any solution. Please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do it by insertMany** for that you need to **use bulk update with upsert option**.

Below are the two different syntax to do it, You man need to loop to create the bulk queries. **(There may be a typo error, code not tested)**

```
var bulk = db.collection_name.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { email: "a@gmail.com" } ).upsert().update( { $set: { fname: "FirstName4", lname: "LastName4", email: "a@gmail.com" } } );
bulk.find( { email: "b@gmail.com" } ).upsert().update( { $set: { fname: "FirstName5", lname: "LastName5", email: "b@gmail.com" } } );
bulk.find( { email: "c@gmail.com" } ).upsert().update( { $set: { fname: "FirstName3", lname: "LastName3", email: "c@gmail.com" } } );
bulk.execute();
```

Another syntax

```
var ops = []

objectsArray.forEach(item => {
    ops.push(
        {
            updateOne: {
                filter: { email: item .email},
                update: {
                    $set: { fname: item.fname, lname: item.lname, email: item.email }
                },
                upsert: true
            }
        }
    )
})

db.collections('collection_name').bulkWrite(ops, { ordered: false });
```

If you are using mongoose check there [BulkWrite Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)

Comment: Is that applicable for mongoose also?

Comment: Yes mongoose support [BulkWrite](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)